# How to reuse the results of df.groupby(). mean in another dataframe to fill NaNs?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working on [the titanic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/GQf0y8ebHO0C4JXscPPp%2Fversions%2FXkNkvXwqPPVG0Qt3MtQT%2Ffiles%2Ftrain.csv).

I compute the mean of `df['Age']` based on 'Sex' and 'Pclass', to fill NaNs in the `df['Age']`.

the code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df['Age'] = df.groupby(['Sex','Pclass'])['Age'].transform(lambda x:x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

This works fine but now, on the test set, I want to **fill NaNs with the values of mean Age grouped by 'Sex' and 'Pclass' from the training set.**
I can easily get the values by `df.groupby(['Sex', 'Pclass'])['Age].mean()`, but I can not figure out how to reuse theses values to fill NaNs in test dataframe.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: df['age'].fillna(df.groupby(['Sex', 'Pclass'])['Age].mean())   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and then replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
mean = df1.groupby(['Sex', 'Pclass'], as_index=False)['Age'].mean()

df2 = df2.merge(mean, on=['Sex','Pclass'], how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
df2['Age'] = df2['Age'].fillna(df2.pop('Age_'))
```

Comment: Thanks you, it is working perfectly as expected! Just for clarification, is there a special reason to change the default column name from `'Age_y'` to `'Age_'`in your proposal?

Comment: @onthemoon01 - Only I want avoid rename columns to `Age_x` and `Age_y`, then is necessary rename in finally data from `Age_x` to `Age`. So if use `suffixes=('','_')` then get `Age` and `Age_` columns and no rename is necessary